# How does Dagger scope and injection work for different scopes?

Tags: android, scope, dagger

Hi I have a question about dagger scope in Android.
Let's say I have the following class

```
class Foo {
    @Inject public Foo(Bar bar) {...}
}


class Bar {
    @Inject public Bar(Damn damn) {...}
}


class Damn {
    @Inject public Damn(@ActivityContext context) {...}
}
```

Question 1: In this case, is it correct to assume that `Foo` and `Bar` will also be automatically always in `ActivityScope` because of `Damn`'s `context`?

Next, I have the following class

```
@ApplicationScope
class HelloWorld {
    private Foo mFoo;

    @Inject HelloWorld(Foo foo) {
        mFoo = foo;
    }

    ...
}
```

Question 2: Will this not even compile because `Foo`, `Bar` and `Damn` are all `ActivityScope` and cannot be injected to `HelloWorld` which as `ApplicationScope`?

Question 3: Without making changes to `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Damn`, is there a way to inject `Foo` object to `HelloWorld` in runtime so that `HelloWorld` can call `Foo`'s method when the app is in the foreground?

Thanks!